# How do I find and select a next bold word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

From the https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/d468759b3587cfb424348fa722765187 , It is possible to select a particular word from the findText, I want to implement the same for bold words only

I have a function to find bold. How do I modify the above gist?

```
var startFlag = x;
var flag = false;

for (var i = x; i < y; i++) {
    if (text.isBold(i) && !flag) {
        startFlag = i;
        flag = true;
    } else if (!text.isBold(i) && flag) {
        flag = false;
        rangeBuilder.addElement(text, startFlag, i - 1);
        doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
        return;
    }
}
if (flag) {
    rangeBuilder.addElement(text, startFlag, i - 1);
    doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain, are you looking for "any bold" or "words with bold" (as say @mr-rebot)?

Comment: Need to search for a particular regular expression which is bold. With an option to also search same without bold also. Using the above algo but not findtext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume another algorithm

```
/*
 * @param {(DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM | DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)} element
 */
function hasBold(element, start) {
  var text = element.editAsText();
  var length = element.asText().getText().length;
  var first = -1;
  var end = -1;
  while (start < length) {
    if (first < 0 && text.isBold(start)) {
      first = start;
    }
    if (first > -1 && !text.isBold(start)) {
      end = start - 1;
      return {
        s: first,
        e: end
      }
    }
    start++;
  }
  if (first > -1) {
    return {
      s: first,
      e: length - 1
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

It's not clean but I've tested it and it works fine.

`hasBold` lets us finding bolds in the current element.

Finally, we have to loop this feature within `document.getBody()`.

You could to get the full code here [find next bold text in google document](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/cfcb7e0ebfe121b881306c527a99bbb2). 
Also you could try [it on a copy](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BkQxCFBY9wyB19U5hzDl_dlAvspYJPDFKkQJJO8ZDE4/copy)

### A new idea

#### The Direct searcing

The best way is to use a callback while it is checked

```
var assay = function (re) {
  var text = re.getElement()
    .asText();
  for (var offset = re.getStartOffset(); offset <= re.getEndOffsetInclusive(); offset++) {
    if (!text.isBold(offset)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function findNextBold() {
  var sp = 'E.';
  Docer.setDocument(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument());
  var rangeElement = Docer.findText(sp, Docer.getActiveRangeElement(), assay);
  rangeElement ? Docer.selectRangeElement(rangeElement) : Docer.setCursorBegin();
}
```

#### The Approx searching

```
 var assay = function(re) {
 var text = re.getElement().asText();

 var startOffset = re.getStartOffset();
 var endOffset = re.getEndOffsetInclusive() + 1;

 for (var offset = startOffset; offset < endOffset; offset++) {
   if (!text.isBold(offset)) return false;
 }

 return this.test(text.getText().slice(startOffset, endOffset));
}

function findNextBold() {

  var searchPattern = '[^ ]+@[^ ]+';
  var testPattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$');
  Docer.setDocument(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument());
  var rangeElement = Docer.findText(searchPattern, Docer.getActiveRangeElement(), assay.bind(testPattern));
  rangeElement ? Docer.selectRangeElement(rangeElement) : Docer.setCursorBegin();

}
```

[Docer](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/afda9eb66a126e656add5f69863b0408)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is possible to find bold text. You need to use [`findText(searchPattern)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern) to search the contents of the element for the specific text pattern using regular expressions. The provided regular expression pattern is independently matched against each text block contained in the current element. Then, use [`isBold()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#isbold) to retrieve the bold setting. It is a *Boolean* which returns whether the text is bold or null.

Comment: How do I use modifier ignore case if I use find text is the above